# MySQL Workbench 6.1 - Error importing recordset

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm going to be getting a new computer soon and I don't want to lose all of the data I have entered in my tables, so I decided to test out the feature that allows you to export and import CSV files. I exported a table successfully (data was transferred to Microsoft Excel in  CSV file), but when I opened the file in Microsoft Excel and added a few rows and tried to import it back in to MySQL Workbench, I got the following error:

```
"Error importing recordset

error calling Python module function
SQLIDEUtils.importRecordsetDataFromFile"
```

I've searched all over for info on this, but can't find any solutions. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Workbench, open a MySQL connection and then navigate to [Server] --> [[Data Export](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-management-data-export.html)]. There are several backup options here, including saving the data as an individual file or folder. Choose the databases you want to export, and then click [Start Export].

If you ever prefer using Excel for editing and such, then use the [MySQL for Excel](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/) plugin to access MySQL databases from within Excel. However, I don't think you need it here.

Comment: MySQL Workbench's data import and export is the best solution for this type of problem (uses mysqldump under the hood).

Answer (score 1):

To export your mySQL data, use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html), which will create all the schema for you.

Excel probably added some stuff to your file and now mySQL can't understand it. The best way to find out is by comparing the files before and after the change.

Answer (score 1):

That error indicates a format problem. If the file is small enough, try opening it in wordpad (or the mac equivalent) and see if there's any difference in the formatting? Could be that the delimiting got a little messed up (this can happen especially with end of row markers in MySQL, I've noticed, it can also happen in mac to pc handoffs). If all else fails you could try exporting using a different format and see if that makes a difference (maybe tsv) when you add new rows.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason can be the line endings used. Depending on the system and editor used to work with the cvs file it the line endings might get changed. For me mysql supported UNIX line endings. And in the editor the line ending had been set to MAC OS 9 since I was using a MAC. 
Changing it to UNIX line ending worked.

Comment: To add on to this: Excel for Mac sets the line endings to Mac. So if you save a CSV file from Excel, you'll need to open the file in a text editor and change the line endings back to Unix before importing with MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 0):

I found that it might be due to a wrong encoding of the input file. 
Using Notepad++ for example (or another similar editor) you need to change file encoding to UTF-8.